# How does the require function takes parameter in Node.js with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-modules

I do not understand what does **(http)** means here in the following javascript code. If its a method it should have been called after a dot. But its not. So what exactly is it?

**var io = require('socket.io')(http)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a function call.

`require('socket.io')` returns a function. The function is then called with parameter `http`.

Maybe this makes it clearer, it's the same thing but with an extra variable assignment:

```js
var factoryFunction = require('socket.io')
var io = factoryFunction(http)
```